# How can I make all site profiles match my network profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

I have updated my profile text on one site (think it was SciFi).
Then I have synced the network profile from this.
Is there a simple way to push the information in the network profile now to all site profiles?

Comment: I had a glance at your profiles and it seems to be consistent across SO, SfiFi&F, EE and also SE main site. Did you click on "Save and copy changes to all public communities" (that's what it does, it updates your profile accordingly in all other public communities)?

Comment: Note that updating one profile and clicking "save and copy changes to all public communities" doesn't affect the network profile itself, for whatever reason. The network profile content isn't copied over to new profiles either, because of an unrelated bug.

Comment: @JeanneDark Fascinating. No, but this is what I was looking for and did not find it.
I just retried to do what I asked for and then I found the (small) sentence "Your profile will be updated on all public communities. If you want, you can customize your profile just on this community.". As I just pressed "save profile", it included the synchronization.
But is this new?
I always did this way and a few minutes ago my SciFi profile was ahead other profiles regarding changes.

Comment: @Zoe Thanks, now I get it. So "save profile" updates all profiles, but not the network profile.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a consistent profile across your public communities and your stackexchange.com network profile, the procedure is the following:

Go to one of your community profiles, <kbd>Edit profile and settings</kbd> and then make the changes you wish. When you're finished, scroll down and press <kbd>Save and copy changes to all public communities</kbd>

[image: "Save and copy changes to all public communities" button]

Now all of your public communities will have that same profile except for your SE network profile. That's the next step and nicely explained with pictures in this [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275694) (this other [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290614) contains a nicer red freehand circle):

1. Go to your network profile
2. Click the "Update profile info" link in the lower right corner below the profile info box
3. Choose a site to update your profile info from (one time copy, so every time you change your profile, you have to do that again)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this is not the same in all communities.
At least in SciFi there was only "save changes", but a separate small link called "customize your profile just on this community.".

Comment: Is this [MSE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619) what you experienced ("User has >1 account, and none have been customized")? Still, it updated your profile everywhere? The point is you update all your (visible community) profiles *and* your SE network profile (in a additional step) via a community profile, not your community profiles via the SE network profile.